# <Object> has no method 'sort'

Tags: javascript, sorting

i have trouble with sorting an object in loop. when i do this code i get an **Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'sort'** . why?) i googled this but doesn't found resolve

```
for (var i = 0; i < responseData.Airlines.length; i++) {

function sortPrice() {

    for (var s = 0; s < responseData.Airlines[i].FaresFull.length; s++) {
        responseData.Airlines[i].FaresFull[s].Pricing.ADTTotal = parseFloat(responseData.Airlines[i].FaresFull[s].Pricing.ADTTotal);

        responseData.Airlines[i].FaresFull[s].sort(function (a, b) {
            return parseFloat(a.Pricing.ADTTotal) > parseFloat(b.Pricing.ADTTotal);
        });

    }
}

sortPrice();

}
```

Comment: Well, you can only sort arrays… Is that `responseData.Airlines[i].FaresFull[s]` an array?

Comment: This is not the cause of your problem but your comparator is invalid.  It returns a boolean but should return (-1, 0, 1) to indicate whether a is (less-than, equivalent-to, greater-than) b.

Comment: You declare a function in a loop (which is invalid) and then call it outside of it???

Comment: js can sort objects, not only arrays

Comment: @RomaPerfilyev yes, if you prototype Sort yourself. What's inside of `FaresFull[s]` ?

Comment: @RomaPerfilyev: No, it cannot. What makes you think so?

Comment: FaresFull[s] an object and have properties which i must compare

Comment: oh sry yes. js cant sort obj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort is a function on array. You are trying to sort an Object. Try this instead:

```
function sortPrice() { 
    for (var i = 0; i < responseData.Airlines.length; i++) {
        for (var s = 0; s < responseData.Airlines[i].FaresFull.length; s++) {
            responseData.Airlines[i].FaresFull[s].Pricing.ADTTotal = 
                  parseFloat(responseData.Airlines[i].FaresFull[s].Pricing.ADTTotal);
        }
        responseData.Airlines[i].FaresFull.sort(function (a, b) {
            return parseFloat(a.Pricing.ADTTotal) - parseFloat(b.Pricing.ADTTotal);
        });
    }
}
```

You were attempting to call sort on each element, instead of sorting the list as a whole. I pulled the sort out of the inner for loop, and switch the comparator to -1,0,1.

Answer (score 2):

Sort method is only available in Array objects. I guess that you're trying to sort an pure Object.

Look: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp here they sort an array

Comment: http://www.w3fools.com/. Better link to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't tell us what you *want* to do or how your data looks I have make a wild guess:

```
// move function header to top
function sortPrice(responseData) {
    for (var i = 0; i < responseData.Airlines.length; i++) {
//      dereference variables
        var airline = responseData.Airlines[i];
        for (var s = 0; s < airline.FaresFull.length; s++) {
            var pricing = airline.FaresFull[s].Pricing;
            pricing.ADTTotal = parseFloat(pricing.ADTTotal);
        }
//      move outside the loop
        airline.FaresFull .sort(function (a, b) {
//                       ^ no [s] - sort the array
//      don't do parseFloat another time
            return a.Pricing.ADTTotal - b.Pricing.ADTTotal;
        });
    }
}

sortPrice(yourData);
```

Comment: yeah, thx to you, thats about to a right resolve and i just get it too and fix my trouble)